# BeautifulSoup Scraping no output

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def findPosts():
    url = 'http://espn.go.com/nba/scoreboard'
    headers = {}
    headers['User-Agent'] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.110 Safari/537.3"
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers = headers).text, "html.parser")
    team1 = soup.find_all('a',{'name' : "&amp;lpos=nba:scoreboard:team"})
    score1 = soup.find_all('td',{'class' : 'total'})
    print(team1)
    print(score1)

findPosts()
```

I am receiving an empty list, but I am sure that the url source code contains the elements that I specified. Is there anything in the BeautifulSoup Documentation that I am using?

Comment: you're receiving an empty list because the `find_all` method returns a list of the WebElements found by the query, and as the answer below says, that content is loaded dynamically.

Comment: But in the webpages current form upon running the program, shouldnt it return the content that is being displayed at the that time/

Comment: not if that content loads through javascript. If it does, like the answer says, then something like `selenium` may be what you need to use instead of bs4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data on that page is dynamically created through Javascript. If you right click in your browser -> view source, and look for the anchors with the name you provided, you will find nothing.
From what I can tell, all of the JSON data for the page to be created is already on the page, so you don't need to make any extra requests to get the data you want.

To find the JSON data on the page, I searched for one of the team names (Mavericks) and saw a massive Javascript object containing what appears to be the data you want to scrape.

Comment: I am just trying to scrap the team names and current scores.

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the json using regex and access the data using dict notation:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re
import json

url='http://espn.go.com/nba/scoreboard'
headers = {}
headers['User-Agent'] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.110 Safari/537.3"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers = headers).text, "html.parser")

script = soup.find_all('script')[7].get_text()
map_search = re.search('^.*?= (\{.*);window.*', script)
mapData = map_search.group(1)
mapDataObj = json.loads(mapData)
scores = mapDataObj['events'][0]['competitions'][0]['competitors'][1]['linescores']
name = mapDataObj['events'][0]['competitions'][0]['competitors'][1]['team']['shortDisplayName']
total_score = mapDataObj['events'][0]['competitions'][0]['competitors'][1]['score']

print 'Team: %s' % name
for score in scores:
  print('Score: %s' % score['value'])
print('Total score: %s' % total_score)
```

Output :

```
Team: Pacers
Score: 19
Score: 24
Score: 27
Score: 30
Total score: 100
```